# How to determine best audio sample rate on Android device?

Tags: android, soundpool

Running `Android 5.1` on my `Nexus 5` I'm experiencing laggy audio due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794965/android-audio-programming-nightmare-soundpool-audiotrack-arrghh) problem. The problem is that my 44.1 KHz `OGG` files are resampled (up to 48 KHz?) on playback using the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class, causing the lag.

Now, I suppose different devices are optimized for different sample rate. How can I make sure that my audio performs well on all devices? Is it possible to detect the optimal sample rate and then choose the best file from multiple audio resources?

Answer (score 2):

You need AudioManager's [PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE)

```
public int getBestSampleRate()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        String sampleRateString = am.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
        int sampleRate = sampleRateString == null ? 44100 : Integer.parseInt(sampleRateString);

        return sampleRate;
    } else {
        return 44100;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've made some tests, please comment if using native sample rate really helps with audio lags.